# Jquery, select dropdown option on Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Jquery with event keyup.
It select dropdownList(CityId) option, which text is liked/samme as a user write in inputbox(finpost).

The problem is that only work once.. I cant see whats wrong ?!
Help

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#finpost').keyup(function ()
    {
        $("#CityId > option").each(function ()
        {
            var t = this.text.toUpperCase();
            if (t.indexOf($('#finpost').val().toUpperCase()) != -1)
            {
                $(this).attr("selected", 'true');
                return false;
            }                
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: check the plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/iDo97jrL5whZBtCQqRqk?p=preview your code seems to work fine, could you recreate your issue there

Comment: Ahmed can you check my last comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now its working. The problem wass this linie:
 $(this).attr('selected', true);..

I changed it to  $(this).prop('selected', true);
and its work

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#finpost').keyup(function () {

        $("#CityId > option").each(function () {
            var t = this.text.toUpperCase();

            if (t.indexOf($('#finpost').val().toUpperCase()) != -1) {

                $(this).prop('selected', true);
                return false;
            }

        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This work only once because your list can have only one selected option per time, but in your script logic you are setting attribute selected to true every time you find a matching without re-initializing others options

I think you should be good to go if you try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#finpost').keyup(function ()
    {
        var matchingFound = false;
        $("#CityId > option").each(function ()
        {
            var t = this.text.toUpperCase();
            if (t.indexOf($('#finpost').val().toUpperCase()) != -1 && !matchingFound)
            {
                $(this).attr("selected", 'true');
                matchingFound = true;
            }
            else {
                $(this).attr("selected", "false");
            }                
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Ahmed you are selecting one option a time but when an other key-up event is fired you will select an other one option without re-initializing the other options (the first one that you have selected)